# Not that criteria

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

In https://askubuntu.com/help/bounty, there's this:
"If there's no answer meeting that criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone."

One criterion, two criteria or "those criteria" but not "that criteria".

Comment: Well how many criteria does it take to screw a light bulb?

Comment: Ask Strunk & White :)

Comment: Well then it's hardly a bug rather a human mistake... :)

Comment: Can you find a more appropriate tag? Bug was the closest. Anyway, this just should be fixed rather than arguing ;)

Comment: No, bug is the correct tag (cc: @MrSeed)

Comment: "the criteria"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text has been updated to "those criteria" ("those criteria" being 1. posted since the bounty started, and 2. earned at least 2 upvotes).